# Error while including sekizai tags in django using django-cms

Tags: django, django-cms

I am very new to django-cms. I just downloaded it using pip install django-cms. It is mentioned that sekizai tags is also a part of it.I used [this site](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/develop/getting_started/tutorial.html) for help. However when I run the app an error "sekizai tags not a valid tag library" is shown and the error is in the base.html in this line at the top {% load cms_tags sekizai_tags %} . Do I have to do anything else ? I added everything neccessary in settings.py and urls.py .Please help

Comment: What version of `django-cms` are you using? Those docs are for the 3.0 beta, not the stable 2.4.2 release. What exactly have you put in your settings (relevant to the sekizai setup)? Have you added `sekizai` to your `INSTALLED_APPS` and added `sekizai.context_processors.sekizai` to your `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`?

Comment: I just had to add 'sekizai' in Installed apps :P. Silly of me. Thanks a lot